# Gwt project is creating cache.js instead of cache.html.Where this configurations are made

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, no-cache

In GWT , I have created two different projects,after compilationone is creating *.cache.html where else other one creating *.cache.js .Please assist why it is happening and where to config thess things.

Answer (score 3):

In your `*.gwt.xml` file you can add a [linker](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLinkers.html).
The standard linker is the `xsiframe`, which generates a `*.cache.js` file.
The `std` linker generates `*.cache.html` file.
Change it by editing the value of `name` in your `*gwt.xml` file:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
```